# Neo4j 3.0.4 Enterprise trial version failed to start in Windows

Tags: windows, neo4j

Neo4j 3.0.4 enterprise version, while trying to install-service or start its show below error. Have tried in different machine also, how to resolve this ?

```
E:\Neo4j\neo4j-enterprise-3.0.4\bin>neo4j.bat install-service -verbose
VERBOSE: Neo4j Root is 'E:\Neo4j\neo4j-enterprise-3.0.4'
VERBOSE: Neo4j Server Type is 'Enterprise'
VERBOSE: Neo4j Version is '3.0.4'
VERBOSE: Neo4j Database Mode is ''
VERBOSE: Install command specified
VERBOSE: Neo4j Windows Service Name is neo4j
VERBOSE: Java detected at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\bin\java.exe'
VERBOSE: Executing C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\bin\java.exe -version
VERBOSE: Java version response: java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
VERBOSE: Java Version detected as 1.8.0_92
VERBOSE: Neo4j Windows Service Name is neo4j
VERBOSE: Reading JVM settings from neo4j-wrapper.conf
Invoke-Neo4j : Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'contains'.
At line:1 char:221
+ try { Unblock-File -Path 'E:\Neo4j\neo4j-enterprise-3.0.4\bin\Neo4j-Management\*.*' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' } catch {};Import-Module 'E:\Neo4j\neo4j-enterprise-3.0.4\bin\Neo4j-Management.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j <<<<  install-service -verbose)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-Neo4j
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Merge-Neo4jJavaSettings.ps1 file in the bin/Neo4j-Management folder has a syntax error in line #68:

```
If (-not $Source.contains($thisSetting)) {
```

Should be

```
If (-not $Source -contains $thisSetting) {
```

For the record, this is occurring for me with the Community edition, so it appears to be a problem with both versions.

Comment: Hi, can you please check my related post ? thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639088/neo4j-3-0-7-enterprise-trial-version-failed-to-start-in-windows

Comment: I have 3.0.3 and there is no Merge-Neo4jJavaSettings.ps1 file, but I get this exact error.

Comment: Well, I don't get the 'Method invocation failed' part. Just goes from 'this may take some time' to the write error.