# Neo4j 3.0.7 Enterprise trial version failed to start in Windows

Tags: windows, neo4j

Windows 7 Pro (64-bit)

I've successfully installed the "service" thanks to both posts [Neo4j 3.0.4 Enterprise trial version failed to start in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383023/neo4j-3-0-4-enterprise-trial-version-failed-to-start-in-windows) and [Missing `server' JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123144/missing-server-jvm-java-jre7-bin-server-jvm-dll).

You may find the corresponding trace below.

```
    C:\Users\bguarism\Dropbox\PORTABLE\MyDBs\neo4j\cnaf_enterprise\bin>neo4j.bat install-service -verbose
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Root is 'C:\Users\bguarism\Dropbox\PORTABLE\MyDBs\neo4j\cnaf_enterprise'
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Server Type is 'Enterprise'
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Version is '3.0.7'
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Database Mode is ''
COMMENTAIRES : Install command specified
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Windows Service Name is neo4j
COMMENTAIRES : Java detected at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'
COMMENTAIRES : Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe -version
COMMENTAIRES : Java version response: java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode, sharing)
COMMENTAIRES : Java Version detected as 1.8.0_101
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Windows Service Name is neo4j
COMMENTAIRES : Reading JVM settings from neo4j-wrapper.conf
COMMENTAIRES : Adding '-XX:+UseG1GC'
COMMENTAIRES : Adding '-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow'
COMMENTAIRES : Adding '-XX:hashCode=5'
COMMENTAIRES : Adding '-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch'
COMMENTAIRES : Adding '-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions'
COMMENTAIRES : Adding '-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields'
COMMENTAIRES : Adding '-XX:+DisableExplicitGC'
COMMENTAIRES : Adding '-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048'
COMMENTAIRES : Adding '-Dunsupported.dbms.udc.source=zip'
COMMENTAIRES : Moving -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions to the beginning
COMMENTAIRES : Reading JVM settings from console java invocation
COMMENTAIRES : Ignoring '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties' as it is already defined
COMMENTAIRES : Ignoring '-Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=zip-powershell' as it is already defined
COMMENTAIRES : Ignoring '-Dorg.neo4j.cluster.logdirectory=data/log' as it is already defined
COMMENTAIRES : Ignoring '-XX:+UseG1GC' as it is already defined
COMMENTAIRES : Ignoring '-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow' as it is already defined
COMMENTAIRES : Ignoring '-XX:hashCode=5' as it is already defined
COMMENTAIRES : Ignoring '-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch' as it is already defined
COMMENTAIRES : Ignoring '-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions' as it is already defined
COMMENTAIRES : Ignoring '-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields' as it is already defined
COMMENTAIRES : Ignoring '-XX:+DisableExplicitGC' as it is already defined
COMMENTAIRES : Ignoring '-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048' as it is already defined
COMMENTAIRES : Ignoring '-Dunsupported.dbms.udc.source=zip' as it is already defined
COMMENTAIRES : Ignoring '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' as it is already defined
COMMENTAIRES : Moving -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions to the beginning
COMMENTAIRES : Installing Neo4j as a service with command line
C:\Users\bguarism\Dropbox\PORTABLE\MyDBs\neo4j\cnaf_enterprise\bin\tools\prunsrv-amd64.exe //IS//neo4j --StartMode=jvm
--StartMethod=start "--StartPath=C:\Users\bguarism\Dropbox\PORTABLE\MyDBs\neo4j\cnaf_enterprise"
"--StartParams=--config-dir=C:\Users\bguarism\Dropbox\PORTABLE\MyDBs\neo4j\cnaf_enterprise\conf"
"++StartParams=--home-dir=C:\Users\bguarism\Dropbox\PORTABLE\MyDBs\neo4j\cnaf_enterprise" --StopMode=jvm --StopMethod=stop
"--StopPath=C:\Users\bguarism\Dropbox\PORTABLE\MyDBs\neo4j\cnaf_enterprise" "--Description=Neo4j Graph Database -
C:\Users\bguarism\Dropbox\PORTABLE\MyDBs\neo4j\cnaf_enterprise" "--DisplayName=Neo4j Graph Database - neo4j" "--Jvm=C:\Program
Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\server\jvm.dll" --LogPath=logs --StdOutput=logs\neo4j.log --StdError=logs\service-error.log
--LogPrefix=neo4j-service --Classpath=lib/*;plugins/*
"--JvmOptions=-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions;-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields;-Dunsupported.dbms.udc.source=zip;-XX:+AlwaysPreTou
ch;-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048;-XX:+UseG1GC;-XX:hashCode=5;-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow;-XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
--Startup=auto --StopClass=org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint
--StartClass=org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint
COMMENTAIRES : Returned exit code 0
Neo4j service installed
```

But Neo4j still fails to start

```
    C:\Users\bguarism\Dropbox\PORTABLE\MyDBs\neo4j\cnaf_enterprise\bin>neo4j.bat start -verbose
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Root is 'C:\Users\bguarism\Dropbox\PORTABLE\MyDBs\neo4j\cnaf_enterprise'
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Server Type is 'Enterprise'
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Version is '3.0.7'
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Database Mode is ''
COMMENTAIRES : Start command specified
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Windows Service Name is neo4j
COMMENTAIRES : Starting the service.  This can take some time...
Invoke-Neo4j : Impossible de démarrer le service « Neo4j Graph Database - neo4j (neo4j) ».
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 271
+ ... t.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j start -verbose)
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-Neo4j
```